# Does adding a supplemental lens attachment to a phone increase the megapixels it can resolve?

Tags: optics, lenses

I am reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_resolution
But am confused if adding a supplemental lens to an imaging system (in this case my phone) would change the amount of information resolved.

The second part of this is question is, does adding a lens change the amount of information you are able to resolve regardless of the physical size of the image you are capturing if the image is filling the entire FOV/corner-to-corner?
-Examples below.

Thanks!

Comment: An imaging system *has* pixels, but it *resolves* features -- usually resolution is described as the minimum line width that can be resolved (or the maximum number of lines across the image that can be resolved).  So, as written, your question is bordering on meaningless.  Could you edit it for clarity?  If you just delete the part that reads "megapixels it can resolve/" you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum feature size that a camera can sense is -- more or less -- the larger of the blur spot diameter (do a web search on "Airy ring") and the pixel size.  When the blur spot is around the same size as a pixel things get complicated -- just ignore that.

You cannot change the number of pixels by changing the lens.

The blur spot size of a lensing system is -- ideally -- limited by diffraction.  In a diffraction-limited lens, the size of the blur spot is proportional to the wavelength divided by the lens's F number, and you cannot increase a lens's F-number by adding more lens elements outside.  So **if the lens is diffraction limited** then you cannot decrease the size of the blur spot.

So far, we're at two strikes.

The only remaining possibility for improvement depends on whether your cell phone lensing system is diffraction limited.  I suspect that most cell phones aren't strictly diffraction limited, but if you *did* have a cell phone camera that wasn't diffraction limited, then you'd have to make a corrective lens *for that specific phone model*, and very possibly for each specific phone.  So in theory -- maybe you could make things a bit better.  In practice, it would take less time grind your own lenses to work with a bare imaging chip, and build your own camera -- and even less time to get a part-time job flipping burgers, and *buy* your own camera.

For the given example -- where you have an 8-1/2 by 11 inch sheet of paper that's filled with QR codes and a microfiche image of that same sheet of paper.  **Assuming that the microfiche image is perfect**, **assuming that you have a perfect microscope**, and **assuming there's no correction you can apply to the phone's lensing system** could get no additional information from the original paper than from the microfiche image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question relates to the amount of data one could resolve from a single image regardless of physical size of the image. An example I was thinking of is, if you had a 8x11 inch piece of paper full of QR codes, and you captured it edge to edge without a supplementary lens, opposed to putting the same 8x11 piece of paper of QR codes on some microfiche and then capturing it with a lens like a microscope lens. The end images would be the same, but from what I gather is that there would be no increase of data due to the limits of the sensor, is this right?

Comment: So a better question for me to ask would have been, what exactly increases data if the system and sensor remain constant?

Comment: Or maybe this relates to density? Its more of a "after the image is captured" question

Comment: Oh, this is interesting. I have the recollection that, twenty years ago, putting a camera up to the eyepiece of an optical system would just kind of ... not work. Now that's usually not the case: astronomy newbies at star parties can get really nice planetary photos by putting their cell phones at the eyepiece of a telescope, and I have great video of peristalsis in a flea's gut that I took by holding a cell camera up to a cheap 25x microscope. Your explanation and my experience suggest that modern cell cameras typically don't operate very close to the diffraction limit.

Comment: @guyintightpants could you *edit your question* with that bit about how much can you resolve from an image regardless of the physical size?  Just so we can be all stack-exchange-y with nice question/answer pairs?

And basically, if you have an F2 lens on your cell phone, and you have an F2 microscope that has the right magnification and the entrance and exit pupils in the right spot, you could capture an image that's .8mm by 1.1mm just as well as your naked phone could capture the same image filling an 8x11 sheet of paper.

Comment: If you're interested in packing the most information into an image and still having it readable by a camera, then you're basically running into some 2D variant of Shannon's Channel Capacity Theorem.

Comment: Edited (hopefully thats better) I have not heard of this theorem, this may be helpful! (shannon hartley thereom or noisy channel? Just looking on wiki) Yes, wondering if you compared the two (8x11 with phone regularly captured, and 8x11 on microfiche, captured with phone through a microscope) if there would be any difference in the overall resolution between the two images. If each image was captured corner-to-corner, so that they look the same.

Comment: Answer expanded!  Claude Shannon's seminal paper is titled "Communication in the Presence of Noise".  I stopped at a Master's degree in general communications theory, and I find it highly accessible -- but I'm pretty steeped in the mathematics related to that discipline, so I'm not sure how that would transfer to someone with a physics background.  I it does have pretty pictures, though :) .  https://web.archive.org/web/20100208112344/http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee104/shannonpaper.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I have to say though, this is way beyond my understanding...(not a physics guy) I'm not sure I'd make it any further than the pictures anyways.....is there something out there that explains this, but with code?  I'm already confused hah

Comment: I'm imagining it comes down to the supplementary lenses power to resolve, though I am not sure how this is measured. For instance, the IBM photostore chip, had a small physical size, and was read by some sort of high powered lens. Which makes me think that the more power to resolve, the more data you receive. Am I wrong about this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolving_power  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113095/discussion-between-guyintightpants-and-timwescott).

Answer (score 1):

No.  A modern digital camera has a chip that is made up of a grid of tiny photosites that are sensitive to light. Each photosite is usually called a pixel, a contraction of "picture element".

Each part of the image is simply one of these pixels.  Think of it as the resolution of a camera.

Lenses cannot add to the number of the photosites on the chip.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But lenses can make blur spots that are larger than the sensor pixels, thus making the overall camera worse than the image sensing chip.

Answer (score 1):

It does not. But it changes the amount of useful information in each pixel, by changing the "solid angle" from which light enters each pixel.

For example, suppose you're taking a photo of the Moon using a camera with a square sensor with 1000 pixels in each direction --- that's one megapixel. (Yes, that's no longer impressive, but it makes the math easy.)  What usually happens is that you are inspired to take the photo because the Moon looks big and pretty to your eye-and-brain optical system, which includes a half-billion years of accumulated trickery, but in your camera you discover that the Moon's apparent diameter is pretty small.  Maybe it's 10% of the width of the image, or 100x100 pixels.  If you're not interested in the rest of the sky, you've just used your one-megapixel camera to take a 10-kilopixel picture. Inefficient, because 99% of your image is boring.

Now you add an optical lens so that the image of the Moon on the sensor is bigger --- maybe 90% of the width, so that the number of interesting pixels is 900x900 = 810 kilopixels. Your sensor is still going to give you its entire megapixel, but now you're going to ignore far fewer of them.

Comment: When it comes to data/information retrieval (answered to Tim) the useful information in each pixel I suppose would be subjective to how I'd write the way to read the information, correct? Regardless of whether or not I use a supplementary lens or make any physical size changes, it sounds like the sensors limits is what I'm mostly dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a lens will only zoom the picture, but does not increase the number of pixels used by the camera to store the picture.

The megapixels of camera cannot be changed by the use of a lens.